# Automatically restart Coldfusion at set intervals on IIS 7.0

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, coldfusion, windows-service

What is the easiest way to tell IIS7 to restart Coldfusion Server at set time intervals (every 6 hours for example) without paying for something like Service Hawk?

Comment: Why do you need to restart so often?  If you're experiencing constant crashes, invest in a tool like FusionReactor or SeeFusion which will give you a lot of insight into what ColdFusion is doing.  Tuning the JVM and adjusting your application code will go a long way toward correcting any stability problems you're experiencing.

Comment: Not so much crashes as it is eating up memory, even with JVM tweaked. Restarting it helps when the mail spooler hangs up. Trying to do the best we can do on a shared hosting for the time being.

Comment: I had problems with my spooler losing contact with Exchange.  There's a solution here that worked for me:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94948/restarting-coldfusion-mail-queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offhand, you could do this with a batch file and Task Scheduler.

The batch file would look something like:

```
net stop "coldfusion 9 application server"
net start "coldfusion 9 application server"
```

The exact details will differ from version to version.

You can then schedule this batch file as often as you want/need.